# Can't find new DLC Not A Hero

Tags: steam, resident-evil-7

Apparently Not A Hero was released yesterday as free DLC for anybody who owned the base Resident Evil 7 game.

However when I check my extra content section of the game I can't see it anywhere?  Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the DLC downloaded on your PC though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging I found a site that had some instructions.  Apparently on Steam it's more of a faff than on console. So here is what I had to do:

1. Go onto the store page and search for Not A Hero
2. Click on the Download button (so far so good)
3. The Download button will automatically open Resident Evil 7
4. The download should begin in the background

For step 3, as noted in the source link below I had to repeat steps 1-3 a few times as the download didn't start.

Source: [How to Start Not A Hero DLC](https://www.primagames.com/games/resident-evil-7-biohazard/tips/resident-evil-7-how-start-not-hero-dlc)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/resident-evil-7-biohazard/tips/resident-evil-7-how-start-not-hero-dlc):

> From the main menu, scroll down the list of options and find the Extra Content listing. Press on this, and it should take you to a screen showcasing all the current DLC available for Resident Evil 7. You should easily spot Not a Hero in this list, right above End of Zoe, the latest DLC for the expansion pass. All you need to do now is just choose the DLC and launch it.

[image]

The DLC doesn't seem to show up when you do so in your case. I can think of two reasons:

- You didn't download the DLC on your Steam Account. If that's the case, look up for it on Steam, and download it first.
- You don't have any safe file for the game. As adviced in the guide, you will then have to play though the main game until you reach the first building, head up the stairs, and save the game with the tape recorder. Then quit to the main menu and try the first operation again.